# How to escape double qootes in Junit 5 a ParametrizedTest with CsvFileSource

Tags: java, junit5, parametrized-testing

When using @ParametrizedTest in Junit 5 with @CsvFileSource, i need a parameter containing double quotes. How do I escape these, i.e. how do i pass exatly `"a test"` as my parameter?

What I have tried:

```
"a test"
""a test""
\"a test\"
"\"a test\""
```

What the parameter is converted to:

```
a test
""a test""
\"a test\"
"\"a test\""
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: The second and fourth ones are spec violations, but I'm also surprised the reader interpreted the string that way.  I'm also surprised the second one and the fourth one didn't concatenate two fields together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @markspace's comment, I noticed the problem is not Junit 5, but the CSV standard. So I tried editing it in LibreOffice instead of a text editor, which gave me the answer:

```
"""a test"""
```

result:

```
"a test"
```

Comment: Findable with a simple Google search: "csv rfc".